# How to know if a record exists in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a table called `person`, when I want to know if the record with `id=1` exists, I will try the following code

```
if Person.query.filter_by(id = 1).count() > 0:
    do_something()
```

The problem is, when there's no record with `id=1`, `flask-sqlalchemy` would just throw an `OperationalError` instead of returning 0. Does it mean the `count` is 0 when `OperationalError` is caught? In other words, should I do it in the following way:

```
try:
    if Person.query.filter_by(id = 1).count() > 0:
        do_something_when_record_exists()
except OperationalError:
    do_something_when_theres_no_record()
finally:
    other_code()
```

It doesn't seem to be an elegant way to me. So is there any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `count` to check if it exists. You can just do this:

```
if Person.query.get(1):
    do something()
```

It will return `None` if there is no record with `id=1`. For other conditions:

```
# filter_by(name='Nancy') for example
if Person.query.filter_by(id=1).first():
    do something()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the database is not consistent with my model, I deleted the database and re-created the table, then everything was working fine.

If everything is right, `Person.query.filter_by(id = 1).count()` should return `0` insteading of throwing an error if there's no record.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists
    if session.query(exists().where(Person.id == 1)).scalar() is not None: #check if id=1 exists
            do_something_when_record_exists()
    else:#else run when no record is present
        do_something_when_theres_no_record()
    other_code()#run it anyway
```

Comment: But `Person.query.filter_by(id = 1).count()` would throw an error, preventing the rest code from running

Comment: @Searene have edited the answer, please can you check now

Comment: Sorry that I created a minimal app and I found that I couldn't reproduce the problem with it. So I was wondering what went wrong with my original app. Maybe it's not a problem with `flask-sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, but the other answers seem incredibly inefficient. This answer should at least generate the correct SQL code unlike the other answers even though the python code to get there is far from ideal:

```
if db.session.query(
    Person.query.filter_by(
                    id = id
            ).exists())
```

This will not fetch the record making it much more efficient. Fetching the record is a waste of bandwidth since it's immediately discarded.